# Slick texture has lines and does not fit

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Today I have encountered a problem while making my game using LWJGL and Slick-Util

My texture is 1280x720 but when I bind it, it looks like this, even though my window is 1280x720:

[Screenshot http://puu.sh/8n2fN.png](http://puu.sh/8n2fN.png)

Cube Renderer:

```
package org.cel.api;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class CubeRenderer
{
    public static void renderCube(float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x,y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+width,y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+width,y+height);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x,y+height);
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

GuiMainMenu

```
package org.cel.client.gui;

import org.cel.api.CubeRenderer;
import org.cel.api.IGui;
import org.cel.api.Resources;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureImpl;

public class GuiMainMenu implements IGui
{

    @Override
    public void update()
    {       
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Resources.getTexture("mainMenu").getTextureID());
        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
        CubeRenderer.renderCube(0, 0, 1270, 710);
        TextureImpl.bindNone();
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyboardEvent(int key, boolean state)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEvent(int button, boolean state, int x, int y)
    {
        System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
package org.cel;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_SMOOTH;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearDepth;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glShadeModel;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport;

import org.cel.api.FontRenderer;
import org.cel.api.IGui;
import org.cel.api.Resources;
import org.cel.client.gui.GuiMainMenu;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class Cel
{
    public static Cel instance;

    public IGui currentGui;

    public FontRenderer fontRenderer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        instance = new Cel();
        instance.main(args, true);
    }

    public void main(String args[], boolean isInstance)
    {
        try
        {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1280, 720));
            Display.setTitle("Cel");
            Display.create();
            initGL();
            Resources.registerTexture("mainMenu", "gui/MainMenu.png");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        gameLoop(args);
    }

    public void gameLoop(String args[])
    {
        currentGui = new GuiMainMenu();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            if(!currentGui.isInitialized)
            {
                currentGui.init();
            }

            currentGui.update();

            input();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(120);
        }
    }

    private void initGL() throws LWJGLException
    {
        glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClearDepth(1);

        glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        fontRenderer = new FontRenderer();
    }

    public void input()
    {       
        while(Keyboard.next())
        {
            currentGui.keyboardEvent(Keyboard.getEventKey(), Keyboard.getEventKeyState());
        }

        while(Mouse.next())
        {
            currentGui.mouseEvent(Mouse.getEventButton(), Mouse.getEventButtonState(), Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot explain the bottom part of your screenshot, but the right-hand side can probably be corrected if you use a `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` repeat mode.

Comment: I am not sure how to use that

Comment: It is a parameter you would pass to `glTexParameteri (...)`. I think that `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is part of the GL12 namespace, so it's probably something along the lines of: `GL11.glTexParameteri (GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);`. If it's not, that should be enough to at least point you i the right direction ;) You need that for `S` and `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visible image is 793x500, while it should be 1270x710, which s exactly (well, rounded to whole pixels) the same ratio as 1280/2048 and 720/1024.To me, this looks like your texture loading code is trying to be intelligent - for a 90s scenario: It creates textures of the next greater power-of-two value (early GPUs did not support non-power-of-two textures), and just uses the sub-image. So you can either change the texcoords (try 1280.f/2048.f instead of 1.0 for the width, and 720.f/1024/f instead of 1.0 for the height), or you some texture loading code which is targeting GPUs from the current millenium.

Comment: I changed them to GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.625f, 0.702f); and it works fine for all textures now (for example if I put 16, 16 before it would do 10x10, now it is 16x16) Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you keep turning off `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, but attempt to bind the texture while it is off. Try removing the`glEnable` + `glDisable` in your CubeRenderer.